# Salesforce Marketing Cloud cloud pages favicon

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, favicon

Is there a chance that I can put a favicon to my cloud pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's no different than adding it to any other HTML page.

```
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://forums.oscommerce.com/favicon.ico"/>
```

This example code piece seems to work fine for me on my test Cloud Page.

Comment: You can't upload .ico files into Content Builder, unfortunately.